# If the range of a laser depends on its crossection perimeter does it mean that a wider beam would reach much longer distances?

Tags: photons, laser, intensity, structural-beam

If the range of a laser depends on its crossection perimeter does it mean that a wider beam would reach much longer distances? Let pressume that we can construct a 1m wide laser beam and as we know that a common laser pointer with 5mm crossection perimeter can reach several kilometers is than right assume that a beam of 1m perimeter can reach 200 times much longer distances as 1000 km until its intensity drops considerably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light from any source can in principle reach any distance. It is just that the light spreads out and causes the intensity to decrease. So what you want to know is how fast the light spreads out with distance. That is given by the [beam divergence angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence). To make life simple, we can assume that the beam has a Gaussian beam profile. Then the beam divergence angle is given by
$$ \theta_B = \frac{\lambda}{\pi w} , $$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light and $w$ is the radius of the beam at its waist (the narrowest point of the beam). Using this expression, you can calculate the how the width of the beam will increase with distance and then you can determine how much the intensity (optical power per unit area) has decreased.